# Syntax error with Forstatement

Tags: java

Hi, I am having an error with line 58 of my code. I'm getting the error:

> Syntax error, insert "; ; ) Statement" to complete For Statement

When I try to compile. I'm trying to make a program that writes a `.txt` file to a `.dat` file. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class PA8
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean a = false;

        while(a == false)
        {
            try
            {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter the name of an input text file");
                String text = keyboard.next();
                BufferedReader inputStream = null;

                inputStream = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(text + ".txt"));
                String inString = inputStream.readLine();

                while(inString != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(inString);
                    int x = Integer.valueOf(inString);
                    inString = inputStream.readLine(); 
                }
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Entry invalid please enter a valid text file name");
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;

        try
        {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter
            (new FileOutputStream("numbers.dat"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("I/O problem: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        while(a == false)
        {
            outputStream.writeInt(x);
        }
        for(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(IOException e)` -- What are you trying to do here?

Comment: comment out : /*  for(IOException e)
 {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }*/

Answer (score 1):

`for(IOException e)` this is an invalid Java for loop statement,

for loop statement should be look like this template :

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
     statement(s)
}
```

Read more a bout [for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) in Java.

And in your case i think that your looking to catching the exception like:

```
catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Also Read more about [try-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) block in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You mistook the declaration of a `for` and a catch of an exception.

your `for(IOException e)` should be a `catch(IOException e)` but you will need another `try`

```
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Anyways, your main error is that you put a `boolean a` and you NEVER change its value, adding `while` looking at this value, you get two `while(true)` in your program so your application will never finish as it is. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to catch an `IOException` that might be thrown in `outputStream.writeInt(x)`, use the following instead of the `while` and `for` loop:

`while (!a) { // !a is equal to (a == false)
    try{ 
        outputStream.writeInt(x);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace(); // Equivalent of System.out.println(e.getMessage())
    }
}`

This catches all `IOExceptions` thrown within the `try` block, and prints them to the console.

Comment: Also note that `x` is out of scope by the time the OP is trying to write it to the `PrintStream`. I'd also say that `e.printStackTrace()` isn't strictly the same as Sysout - `printStackTrace()` uses the `System.err` stream instead of `System.out`.

Comment: @JonK you are correct, I was implying that both appear in the console, but it is a better practice to print stacktraces in `System.err`

Answer (score 0):

There are two error in your program
1> you have not declare varible x which is used in while loop
2> syntax used for for loop is wrong
syntax of for loop is for(;;) 
    more details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)